# Loopback 4 find() not working inside the cron job implementation

Tags: node.js, express, cron, loopback4

I have tried to implement cronjob in my loopback 4 application. I have followed the given github repository

[https://github.com/dhmlau/cron-test/tree/master](https://stackoverflow.com)

`cronjob.ts`:

```
import { CronJob, cronJob } from "@loopback/cron";
import { repository } from "@loopback/repository";
import { Schedule } from "../models/schedule.model";
import { ScheduleRepository } from "../repositories/schedule.repository";

@cronJob()
export class MyCronJob extends CronJob {
    constructor(
    @repository(ScheduleRepository)
    public scheduleRepository: ScheduleRepository
    ) {
    super({
      name: "job-B",
      onTick: async () => {
        // do the work
        let schedule: Schedule[] = await this.findSchedule();
        console.log(new Date());
        console.log(schedule);
      },
      cronTime: "*/1 * * * *",
      start: false
    });
    }

    async findSchedule(): Promise<Schedule[]> {
    console.log(new Date());

    const dailyRuns = await this.scheduleRepository.find({ where: { isEnabled: true } });
    console.log(dailyRuns)
    return dailyRuns
    }
    }
```

`application.ts`:

```
this.component(CronComponent);
this.add(createBindingFromClass(MyCronJob));
```

I didn't get the response from the find method. On each minute the log for new Date() has been logged, but dailyRuns not getting logged